# How to manage ties in mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have this tables

```
CREATE TABLE `autores` (
`id_autor` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`login` varchar(60) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`password` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`correo` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`url` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '');

CREATE TABLE `noticias` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`autor_id` char(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`fecha_pub` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`contenido` longtext NOT NULL,
`titulo` text NOT NULL,
UNIQUE KEY `in1` (`id`),
FULLTEXT KEY `full` (`titulo`,`contenido`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3844 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Now i've created a procedure that calculates who's the author that has the most "articles" published.

```
create procedure masnoticiasmes(in mes int)
begin
declare empate int default 0;
declare nombreautor VARCHAR(30);
declare cantidad, autor, autormax int;
declare maximo, fin  int default 0;
declare nombreautor2,nombreempate char(30);
declare empatado char(30);
declare micursor cursor for select count(id), autor_id  from noticias where month(fecha_pub)=mes group by autor_id;
declare continue handler for not found set fin=1;
open micursor;
repeat
fetch micursor into cantidad, autor;
if fin=0 then
if cantidad>maximo  then 
set maximo=cantidad;
set autormax=autor;
set empate=0;      
end if;
if cantidad=maximo and autormax != autor then

set empatado=autor;
set empate=empate+1;
end if;
end if;
until fin end repeat;
select login from autores join noticias on  noticias.autor_id=autores.id_autor where cantidad IN (maximo) into nombreempate;
close micursor;

select login from autores join noticias on noticias.autor_id=autores.id_autor where autores.id_autor=empatado into nombreempate;

select concat ( "El que mas ha publicado es el: ", nombreautor2," con ", maximo, " noticias ", " empatados ", empate,nombreempate) as "resultado";
end//
```

Now my problem is that when a tie happens , i have to say

the most published author is X (because of the way cursor works it picks up the first most published even if there's a tie) then it says there are X ties
and the author that has a tie is X , the problem is that the most published author is a variable , and when there's a tie between 2 it works fine , just selecting from the table the name of the author where the id is the author id.
But if there are more than 2 authors , i would have to store the name in a variable , 1 variable for every author that ties is just not doable , how would you do it?

Comment: If it was me, I'd provide a sample data set, and a desired result.

Comment: mysql> call masnoticiasmes(11)//
    +-------------------------------------------------------+
    | concat("Most published author is",nombreautor2) |
    +-------------------------------------------------------+
    | Most published author is  autor1                  |
    +-------------------------------------------------------+
    1 row in set (0.35 sec)

+------------+
| TIES   |
+------------+
| 5 autor3   |
| 5 autor288 |
+------------+